# My UIScrollView bounces back to the top when i let it go

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have two problems with my UIScrollView, first, when i launch the app, the first screen i see is the one which contain the UIScrollView, so i try to scroll but i couldn't, it like if it is locked, so i navigate to other screens in the app, and when i go back to the first screen it scrolls very well.
the second problem is that when i scroll down and since i let the UIScrollView go, it bounces back to the top and so i can't interact with the content I just scrolled to.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

check the @property contentSize. I bet it is set to CGSizeZero.

The height must be set to the maximum Y of the last element (in terms of Y-position) of your scrollView subviews.

You might want to have a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) page, it has a lot of information regarding the UIS